# VB.Net Printing PDF Fails (But equivalent works from PowerShell)

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing, process

I'm trying to write a small desktop app that just sits around and prints files as they get downloaded.

Sending a PDF file to the printer with PowerShell works fine and it prints:

```
.\AcroRd32.exe /N /T C:\Path\to\201402124_label.pdf "Brother QL-700"
```

However, doing the same in Visual Studio 2012 does not work. The Adobe Reader window opens with the label, and closes, but the file never show up at the printer to be printed. This doesn't make sense because this same code is currently working to send larger PDFs to a duplex printer in the same manner (just using a different printer saved in My.Settings):

```
For Each file As IO.FileInfo In files

    If file.CreationTime > My.Settings.LastRunDate Then

        MsgBox(file.Name)

        Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        Dim proc As Process = New Process

        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        startInfo.Verb = "print"
        startInfo.Arguments = My.Settings.LabelPrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        startInfo.FileName = file.FullName

        proc.StartInfo = startInfo
        proc.Start()

        proc.WaitForInputIdle()
        proc.CloseMainWindow()

    End If

Next
```

I can't figure out why doing this over the CLI/PowerShell works, but not inside VB.net

Comment: Also, please add what you mean by "does not work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply use [`Process.Start(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Much more straight forward and clean. You can then use the returned `Diagnostics.Process` to run your other commands like `WaitForInputIdle()`.

You would probably use something like this:

```
Dim proc As Process = Process.Start("AcroRd32.exe", _
                              String.Format("/N /T {0} ""{1}""", _
                              "C:\Path\to\201402124_label.pdf", "Brother QL-700")
```

Comment: No problem. Have fun coding.